# Webform and Mosaico

Tags: webform-civicrm, mosaico

Is it possible to use a Mosaico template within Webform-civicrm?

I can copy paste the code but what if I want to select a template, which is easier to manage if the code evolves frequently.

regards

Guillaume

Comment: i very much doubt it. you may be able to copy the html from the db but am just speculating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asking an other question drove me to the best option. I am not sending the confirmation email within webform but rather with a [civirule](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/34260/6991). It's more efficient and also brings more possibilities.